# How do you annotate a nested Java class for Swagger?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

I'm using the swagger-springmvc integration to annotate my Java code to produce a Swagger definition. All was going well until I got to a request class (posted to my controller) that contains a reference to another class:

```
@ApiModel(value = "description")
public class MyRequest {
    private MyOtherClass aclass;
    ...
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "description", required = true)
    public MyOtherClass getAclass() {
        return aclass;
    }
    ...
}
```

In another file MyOtherClass is annotated in the same way:

```
@ApiModel(value = "description")
public class MyOtherClass {
    public String anAttribute;
    ...
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "description", required = true)
    public String getAnAttribute() {
        return anAttribute;
    }
    ...
}
```

When viewed in the Swagger UI, the MyOtherClass model is not in the generated definition and the request object is just shown as a string:

```
{
  "aclass": "MyOtherClass",
  ...
}
```

Rather than:

```
{
  "trips": [
     {
        "anAttribute" : ""
     }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Am I missing an annotation somewhere or is this a limitation? It seems like there should be some way to force the class to be included in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an error on swagger-springmvc <= 0.8.2, they were not resolving the complete tree of attributes through reflection. Now, with version 0.8.8 it is really simple to configure Swagger for your Spring project, and this problem has been successfully solved.
You don't need to add any special additional annotation!. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks @javierfdr. Upgraded and it auto-discovers and displays correctly as promised!